# Making Pagination work with home.php

Tags: php, wordpress

I can't seem to create a proper numeric pagination links on my `home.php` (i.e. the page containing all the posts sorted by date). Been scouring the WP developer handbook, Google and Stack Overflow for answers, to no avail.

Here's how my `home.php` file looks so far:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var('paged' ) : '1';
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'paged' => $paged
);
$the_query = new WP_Query($args);
?>
<!-- The Main Loop is here -->
<?php
$big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer

echo paginate_links( array(
    'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
    'format' => '%#%',
    'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
    'total' => $the_query->max_num_pages
) );
?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

In my development site, I have 7 sample posts. The first page (i.e. the  5 most recent posts) get rendered the way I want it. But when you click one of the numbered page links, it re-directs to the proper URL format but instead of using the `home.php` as the template file, it instead uses the `404.php`. I may be missing something here but I can't seem to figure out what.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Set in wp-admin >> settings >> reading set blog posts to show as 5.

Comment: WHOA THAT ACTUALLY WORKED. Can you explain how that simple change mattered??? (Also, if you could care to add that as an actual answer so I can mark it as the answer for people who will see this question in the future.

Comment: sure i will make it as answer

Comment: answer added as it will help others with similar issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to add pagination to your defaul `post` provided by wordpress then you have to follow below step so pagination will work.

-> Set in wp-admin >> settings >> reading set blog posts to show as 5(number you want to display posts per page).

As whatever posts_per_page you want just set it.Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Replace  with the pagination code below:

```
<div class="pagination">
    <?php 
        echo paginate_links( array(
            'base'         => str_replace( 999999999, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( 999999999 ) ) ),
            'total'        => $query->max_num_pages,
            'current'      => max( 1, get_query_var( 'paged' ) ),
            'format'       => '?paged=%#%',
            'show_all'     => false,
            'type'         => 'plain',
            'end_size'     => 2,
            'mid_size'     => 1,
            'prev_next'    => true,
            'prev_text'    => sprintf( '<i></i> %1$s', __( 'Newer Posts', 'text-domain' ) ),
            'next_text'    => sprintf( '%1$s <i></i>', __( 'Older Posts', 'text-domain' ) ),
            'add_args'     => false,
            'add_fragment' => '',
        ) );
    ?>
</div>
```

WordPress comes with a handy function called `paginate_links()` which does the heavy lifting. In the example above, the custom WP_Query object `$query` is used instead of the global `$wp_query` object.